Show single event per row in mobiscroll timeline (Angular)
we have one user case where we need to show single event per row (resource) in the mobiscroll timeline
if there are multiple events on similar time duration it should show in stacked way, regardless of its overlaping or not. How we can achive it in mobiscroll timeline ?
all events should be shown in stacked manner
